# Add-Migration command not working in EF 7 for UWP app

Tags: sqlite, uwp, entity-framework-core

I'm following [getting started with EF 7 for UWP apps](http://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/uwp.html) official tutorial.

When I'm at Add-Migration MyFirstMigration, it throws following error:

```
PM> Add-Migration MyFirstMigration

Add-Migration : Exception calling "CreateInstanceAndUnwrap" with "8" argument(s): "Could not load file or assembly 'AppShellProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' 
or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-Migration MyFirstMigration
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-Migration], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : BadImageFormatException,Add-Migration
```

Has anyone figured out any workaround?

Comment: It works well for me. Have you followed exactly the same steps on a blank UWP app project? What is the AppShellProject, your own project or get by NuGet? Can you find it in project.json?

Comment: @AlanYao-MSFT I changed target to x86 (earlier it was x64) & it worked. Thanks, you saved my day & weeks (I was thinking to learn SQLite-Net). I made this change after viewing project.json. Why doesn't it work for x64? Please add this as answer, so that I'll mark question as resolved :)

Comment: You might be hitting issue [#1058](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/1058).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great job @Anil. :)

Actually, since this kind of issue may be related to Visual Studio tools or NuGet. By searching "CreateInstanceAndUnwrap Add-Migration" in EF repository on GitHub, you will see some [issues](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/search?q=CreateInstanceAndUnwrap&type=Issues&utf8=%E2%9C%93) there. If you cannot find any existing issues next time, as same as the questions(project.json, project type and etc. ) I asked, try to find out what's the difference between your steps/configurations and the tutorial will be helpful and you will have more info to get a quick answer.

I believe @bricelam has pointed out the issue you encountered, and no one is more familiar with EF7 than him. I want to pick some key messages from @bricelam in that issue as the ending:

> Correct, the Migration commands won't work with x64 assemblies. The current implementation executes inside of an AppDomain created from VS (devenv.exe) which is a 32-bit process.
>
> you'll have to use x86 at design-time.